# How is nextLine() discarding input in this code?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

If I remove input.nextLine() from the catch block, an infinite loop starts. The coment says that input.nextLine() is discarding input. How exactly is it doing this?

```
import java.util.*;

public class InputMismatchExceptionDemo {
public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
boolean continueInput = true;

do {
  try {
    System.out.print("Enter an integer: ");
    int number = input.nextInt();

    // Display the result
    System.out.println(
      "The number entered is " + number);

    continueInput = false;
  } 
  catch (InputMismatchException ex) {
    System.out.println("Try again. (" + 
      "Incorrect input: an integer is required)");
    input.nextLine(); // discard input 
  }
} while (continueInput);
}
}
```

One more thing.. The code listed below, on the other hand, works perfectly without including any input.nextLine() statement. Why?

```
import java.util.*;

public class InputMismatchExceptionDemo {
public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter four inputs::");
int a = input.nextInt();
int b = input.nextInt();
int c = input.nextInt();
int d = input.nextInt();
int[] x = {a,b,c,d};
for(int i = 0; i<x.length; i++)
    System.out.println(x[i]);
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `input.nextInt();` will only consume an `int`, there is still pending characters in the buffer (that are not an `int`) in the catch block. If you don't read them with `nextLine()` then you enter an infinite loop as it checks for an `int`, doesn't find one, throws an `Exception` and then checks for an `int`.

You could do

```
catch (InputMismatchException ex) {
    System.out.println("Try again. (" + 
      "Incorrect input: an integer is required) " +
      input.nextLine() + " is not an int"); 
}
```

Comment: I replaced my catch block with the one you provided. Here's the console output:

Enter an integer: 5.4
Try again. (Incorrect input: an integer is required) 5.4 is not an int.

I can't understand, why is input.nextLine giving 5.4? Shouldn't it be a newline character ('\n')

Comment: @Saud Not in your first example. It didn't read `5.4` as an `int`, because `5.4` **isn't** an `int`. Thus the `InputMismatchException`, *it tries to read an `int` but there isn't an `int` to read; there is `5.4` ready to read (and `readInt` will not read `5.4`)*. Your second example would terminate if you entered `5.4` for `a`, `b`, `c` or `d`.